# Ansible - Fetch a collection of files to the destination without copying remote host's file structure?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook doing the following to copy all txt files from a remote host directory to my source dir.

```
- name: Find files to copy
find: paths="/tmp/foo" recurse=no patterns="*.txt"
register: files_to_copy
- name: Copy files
fetch: src={{ item.path }} dest=/tmp/foo_files
with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.files }}"
```

If 2 remote hosts (for example domainA.com and domainB.com) have foo.txt and bar.txt in their separate respective tmp/foo directories, I would like the end result on the host directory to be:

> /tmp/foo_files/
>
> foo.txt
>
> bar.txt

What I get instead from running above is that the host directory contains:

> /tmp/foo_files/domainA.com/tmp/foo/foo.txt
>
> /tmp/foo_files/domainB.com/tmp/foo/bar.txt

Answer (score 6):

You can set `flat: yes` in the `fetch` task, ref. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html

> Allows you to override the default behavior of appending hostname/path/to/file to the destination. If dest ends with '/', it will use the basename of the source file, similar to the copy module. Obviously this is only handy if the filenames are unique.

```
- name: find files to copy
  find: 
    paths: "/tmp/foo"
    recurse: no 
    patterns: "*.txt"
  register: files_to_copy

- name: Copy files
  fetch: 
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: /tmp/foo_files/
    flat: yes
  with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.files }}"
```